# How do I Calculate theoretical acceleration and distance needed to reach max theoretical speed of an Electric RC using single gear ratio?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I’m trying to work out how to set up a spreadsheet to calculate the acceleration and distance needed in order to reach a theoretical top speed for an electric RC car. The speeds we are talking about are an excess of 200 mph. I am able to calculate whether or not the power system will be able to physically move the vehicle but I do not have a way to calculate theoretical acceleration and distance needed. I have the following parameters available to me:

Motor watts output, motor maximum rpm, voltage, current, differential gear ratios, transmission gear ratio, final drive ratio, weight of the vehicle, wheel diameter, RPM at the wheel at maximum rpm,  and the values would take voltage drop into consideration. I have been able to work out theoretical TopSpeed but I am trying to calculate the minimum distance required and what the average acceleration ability of the system is given the aforementioned information. The reason is that I am doing speed testing and have learned that  there are some tricky details I need to consider. “Gearing for the length of available road” is the name of this game. This will help me have a better idea of the gearing range I’ll need to choose if working with a 3500’ stretch of road vs a 1200’ stretch or even 132’. If someone is able to help me understand which formulas best define what I’m after, I’ll be able to create a spreadsheet so that I can use a drop down menu showing different road lengths using theoretical top speed to determine the minimum length of road needed and also account for deceleration distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just write you the equations

the acceleration is:

$$a=\frac{r\,i_G\,i_H\,\tau_E}{M\,r^2+4\,I_w}$$

the speed  is $~v=a\,t~$ and the distance is $~x=v\,t~$

- $M~$ car mass $~[kg]$
- $I_W$ wheel inertia $~[kg\,m^2]~$
- $r ~~$ wheel radius $~[m]~$
- $i_G~$ gear transmission rate $~-$
- $i_H~$ differential transmission rate$~-$
- $\tau_E~=\frac{P}{n_{RC}\pi/30}~$ RC torque $~[N\,m]$
- $n_{RC}~$ max RPM

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this! I greatly appreciate your help and will try this out. I’ll let you know if it is in accord with final results:)